# Fetch particular row of data

Tags: iphone, sqlite, uibutton, nsarray

I have stored some images in database table. I am using UIActionsheet buttons to display different set of images. When I click button1 it should display button1 images. But, when I click, all the images are getting displayed instead of displaying images for specific rows.

code:

category table:

```
id cat_name

1   Imageset1
2   Imageset2
3   Imageset3
```

product table:

```
id  cat_id   product_image
1    1         image1.png
2    1         image2.png
3    1         image3.png
4    2         nature1.png
5    2         nature2.png
6    3        animal.png
```

Query for fetch images:

```
const char *sql = "SELECT id,cat_id,product_image FROM product where cat_id";

while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {


                catName = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                           (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
                NSLog(@"catName is %@",catName);

                [mArray addObject:catName];

}
```

UIActionSheet button index for click:

```
    -(void)actionSheetClickedButtonAtIndex:(int)buttonIndex {

        if (buttonIndex == 0) {
            NSLog(@"button");

for (int i = 0; i<[mArray count]; i++ ) {

    [imgView1 setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[mArray objectAtIndex:i]]
                                 forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}

    } else if (buttonIndex == 1) {

for (int i = 0; i<[mArray count]; i++ ) {

    [imgView2 setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[mArray objectAtIndex:i]]
                                 forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}

    }

    }
```

Here mArray displaying all the images. Button Index 0 for only Imageset1 having cat_id=1 images. The Button Index 1 having Imageset2 having cat_id=2 images. The buttons are having name of cat_name from categories table.

Comment: mArray having product table images

Comment: can you delete my server url?

Comment: can you come to chat?

Comment: Sure. Shall I see you in chat here? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35899/discussion-between-rob-and-user2674668

Answer (score 0):

Create method that return array of images according to category  from table and use this array in the action sheet. Following is my code may be its help you

```
-(NSMutableArray *)getImages:(int)index {

   char *st;

    NSMutableArray *arraylistget  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    st = sqlite3_mprintf("SELECT product_image FROM product Where cat_id=%d",index);

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(rlraDb, st, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

        // step through each row in the result set
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {


            const char* image = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);

           /* NSMutableDictionary *dictObject = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

            [dictObject setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",image] forKey:@"ProfileImage"]; */

            [arraylistget addObject:image];

        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    sqlite3_free(st);

    NSLog(@"arrScannerProfileIDs: %@",arraylistget);
    return arraylistget;
}


-(void)actionSheetClickedButtonAtIndex:(int)buttonIndex {
     if (buttonIndex == 0) {

          NSLog(@"button");

         mArray = [self getImages:1];

         for (int i = 0; i<[mArray count]; i++ ) {

               [imgView1 setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[mArray objectAtIndex:i]]
                                     forState:UIControlStateNormal];
          }

      } else if (buttonIndex == 1) {

             mArray = [self getImages:2];

             for (int i = 0; i<[mArray count]; i++ ) {

             [imgView2 setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[mArray objectAtIndex:i]]
                                     forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            }

      }

 }
```

Comment: shall i use mArray or arraylistget?

Comment: see my code  '[self getImages:1]' that return array and store in the "mArray" here is my code line   "mArray = [self getImages:1];"

Comment: Still you have any question,ask me.

Comment: when i click the button i got this error:  NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSPlaceholderString initWithUTF8String:]: NULL cString

Comment: Use this code : [imgView1 setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithCString:[mArray objectAtIndex:i] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]
                                     forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36307/discussion-between-user2674668-and-divya-bhalodiya)